# Printing Nepali CHaracters from Software

Tags: c#, unicode, printing, fonts

I am trying to print a bill from my software that contains Nepali characters. It works with the same code base on another computer but doesn't work on mine. is there something I need to install or change?

[A demo front-end display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBsU2.png)
[Demo Print Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX3jD.png)

follow-up question. I am trying to change the formatting of my printing but I do not seem to find it anywhere. This is the only code I have in code behind. This is my front and backend code

```
   <div class="row-fluid voffset5">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="well">
                <asp:Button ID="btn_POST" runat="server" class="btn-Save pull-right hoffset0" Text="Post"
                    Width="100px" ToolTip="Print Billing Invoice" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_PRINT" runat="server" class="btn-Edit pull-right" Text="Print"
                    Width="100px" ToolTip="Print Billing Invoice" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btn_PRINT_Click" />
                <%--<asp:Button ID="btn_FIRST" runat="server" class="btn-Edit pull-left"
                    Text="<<" Width="40px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ToolTip="First Record" OnClick="btn_FIRST_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_PREVIOUS" runat="server" class="btn-Edit pull-left hoffset0"
                    Text="<" Width="40px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ToolTip="Previous Record" OnClick="btn_PREVIOUS_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_NEXT" runat="server" class="btn-Edit pull-left hoffset0" Text=">"
                    Width="40px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ToolTip="Next Record" OnClick="btn_NEXT_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_LAST" runat="server" class="btn-Edit pull-left hoffset0" Text=">>"
                    Width="40px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ToolTip="Last Record" OnClick="btn_LAST_Click" />--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    private void print_Billing_Invoice()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.cb_DOCUMENT_NO.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                //Vat/Pan No
                cusBAL._customer_no = this.cb_INDUSTRY_NAME.SelectedValue;

                Session["VatPanNo"] = cusBAL.set_Customer_Vat_Pan_No();
                Session["DocumentNo"] = this.cb_DOCUMENT_NO.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Session["Industry"] = this.cb_INDUSTRY_NAME.SelectedItem;
                Session["Date"] = this.txt_POSTING_DATE.Text;
                Session["RegionId"] = this.txt_REGION_ID.Text;

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('bi_ac_vr_Billing_Invoice.aspx');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                this.divM.Visible = true;
                this.lM.Text = " Document No cannot be blank!";
                this.txt_POSTING_DATE.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogging.SendExcepToDB(ex);
            ExceptionLogging.SendExcepToDB(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not give much information. In a web browser? Try to use (and include) a webfont with Nepali characters. Then I think different browsers, and operating system version may have different support (IIRC Nepali has own typographical rules which cannot be done just with font programming. Is it also possible that a language pack is needed. More info needed.